# jQuery Toggle show/hide on the span action

Tags: jquery

I have the following list:

```
    <div id="topicListContainter">
            <ul id="sList" class="sList">
                    <li id="itemList_11">
                        0. updated  <span class="closeBox" id="11" ><img  src="images/close.png"></span>                                   
                        <div id="comment_actions" class="comment_actions" style="display: none; margin: 5px"><textarea style="width: 100%"></textarea>
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" id="date" class="date" /> <input style="margin: 5px" type="button" class="button blue" value="Save" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="itemList_27">
                        1. Sta ima  <span class="closeBox" id="27" ><img  src="images/close.png"></span>                                   
                        <div id="comment_actions" class="comment_actions" style="display: none; margin: 5px"><textarea style="width: 100%"></textarea>
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" id="date" class="date" /> <input style="margin: 5px" type="button" class="button blue" value="Save" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="itemList_26">
                        2. Update 22  <span class="closeBox" id="26" ><img  src="images/close.png"></span>                                   
                        <div id="comment_actions" class="comment_actions" style="display: none; margin: 5px"><textarea style="width: 100%"></textarea>
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" id="date" class="date" /> <input style="margin: 5px" type="button" class="button blue" value="Save" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                        .....
```

How can I toggle and show/hide the `<div>` `comment_actions` on the click of the action of `closeBox`

Note: each `<li>` has its own `comment_actions` div

So far I have tried something like:

```
jQuery('.closeBox').live('click', function() {   
        jQuery(this).next('div').hide();
});
```

Comment: why is `.closeBox` display none? and why is the id `comment_actions` not unique?

Comment: @Adnan Glad you solved your problem and thanks for marking my answer as the accepted answer. Would it be too much trouble to ask for an upvote as well? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ec6dc/3/).**

I would add a `data` property to your comments `div` blocks that matches the id of the `span` being clicked. Then you can select `.toggle()` method to show hide as many other `div` blocks as you want with the matching `data` property using a data selector.

I also removed the `display:none;` from the `closebox` span so it could actually be clicked.

```
0. updated  
<!-- Note the data-comments property added here -->
<span class="closeBox" id="11" data-comments="11" >
    <img  src="images/close.png">
</span>                                   

<!-- Note the data-comments property added here -->
<div id="comment_actions" data-comments="11" class="comment_actions" style="display: none; margin: 5px">
    <textarea style="width: 100%"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="date" class="date" /> 
    <input style="margin: 5px" type="button" class="button blue" value="Save" />
</div>​

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.closeBox').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(e.target).parent();
        $('div[data-comments="' + $target.data('comments') + '"]').toggle();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was close.

Remove the `display: none` from the `span.closedBox` and try this:

```
jQuery('.closeBox').live('click', function() {   
        jQuery(this).next('div.comment_actions').toggle();
});
```

Also, avoid using the attribute `id` value in more than one element. (no duplicates of `id`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.closeBox').bind('click', function() {
  $('.comment_actions').toggle();
});
```

If you want a little more functionality check this out:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: This will toggle all the comments, you should use `next()`